# RSpec ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec

I am having difficulty getting a test to pass:

Error:

```
Failure/Error: post :create, { appointment: { dentist_id: '1', patient_id: '2', appt_date: '2015-12-05 09:00:00' } }
 ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
   Couldn't find Dentist with 'id'=
```

Appointment Controller:

```
def create
 @dentist = Dentist.find(params[:dentist_id])
 @appointment = @dentist.appointments.new(appointment)
  if Appointment.exists?(:appt_date => @appointment.appt_date)
   render :new
  else
   @appointment.save
   redirect_to dentist_path(@dentist)
  end
end
```

Appointment Spec:

```
describe 'POST #create' do
 it 'assigns a newly created appointment as @appointment' do
  post :create, { appointment: { dentist_id: '1', patient_id: '2', appt_date: '2015-12-05 09:00:00' } }
  expect(assigns(:appointment)).to be_a(Appointment)
  expect(assigns(:appointment)).to be_persisted
 end
end
```

What am I missing?  Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your request, you're doing `post :create, { appointment: { dentist_id: '1', ... } }`, which means that `params[:dentist_id]` in your controller will be `nil` (notice how you're nesting `dentist_id` under `appointment` in your request params). To fix this, change `@dentist = Dentist.find(params[:dentist_id])` in your controller action to `@dentist = Dentist.find(params[:appointment][:dentist_id])`, or change your request to `post :create, { dentist_id: '1', appointment: { patient_id: '2' ... } }`.

**Update**

You'll also need to create a `Dentist` record in your database before the test is run. To do that, add something like this to your test case:

```
describe 'POST #create' do
  before { Dentist.create!(id: 1) }

  it 'assigns a newly created appointment as @appointment' do
    post :create, { dentist_id: '1', appointment: { patient_id: '2', appt_date: '2015-12-05 09:00:00' } }
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: I have attempted your solution and now receive the following error: Failure/Error: post :create, { dentist_id: '16', appointment: { patient_id: '2', appt_date: '2015-12-05 09:00:00' } }
     ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
       Couldn't find Dentist with 'id'=16

Comment: well do you have a dentist with ID 16 in your test database?

Comment: That's probably because a `Dentist` record with ID `16` doesn't exist. Updated my answer to include instructions for creating a `Dentist` record before your test is run.

Comment: I can't believe the obvious escaped me.  I was able to get the test to pass.  I sincerely appreciate your help.